# is It efficient to use too many stream builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test, stream-builder

I have build chat app in flutter and socket.io as backend

There's a feature where user can react to a message as [':love:' , ':joy:' , ':like:' ]

To handle this i have cretaed socket method as

client side code as

```
  SocketConnection.socket.on('reaction', (data) {
        print('listening to `reaction` $data ');
        //send data to reaction stream
      });
}

 static emitReaction(data) {
   
     socket.emit('reaction', data);
  }
```

To show the messages I am using AnimatedList and whenever a new message arrives or a message is deleted I insert or remove the item from list and notify it

Now to implement reaction, I have two ways:
1) listen to a stream of reaction in the area where I am listening to messages and update the animated list using setState and the whole list gets rebuild when a user react to a message.

2) OR I should create a statlessWidget of Chatbubble as a child of stream builder and each message individually listens to the 'reaction' stream and gets updated when there's some reaction to a specific message.

So my doubt is, is it an efficient method to use stream builder for each message? Performance is the main concern.